# problem displaying bitmap from native code in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

I am facing problem with displaying bitmap using native code. My code is as below

Native Code

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_app_Panel_renderbitmap(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,  jobject bitmap, jlong time_ms)
 {
 AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
void*              pixels;
int                ret;

if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
    return;
}

if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565) {
    return;
}

if ((ret =AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
}

memcpy(pixels, pictureRGB, 480*320);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```

Java Code

```
         Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 320, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
         renderbitmap(mBitmap, 0);
         canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

And my Application is crashing at memcpy, in which pictureRGB is declared as 
       int *pictureRGB[4];

All the pixels are inside the pictureRGB. Is there anything wrong the way i am doing? Am passing correct values to bitmap and memcpy?

Comment: Isn't `renderbitmap` expecting 4 parameters? And can you post the actual error?

Comment: Actual error  when I debug I can see SIGSEGEV at memcpy. Don't know whether I am sending less number of bytes or more? renderbitmap expects 2 parameters, as the other two are jni default.

Comment: Hi Android007, What is exually the reason you do this in native code. Do you have memory or performance advantages? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should declare `pictureRGB` as follows:

```
uint16_t *pictureRGB;
pictureRGB = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*480*320);
```

And then to copy the pixels do the following:

```
memcpy(pixels, pictureRGB, 480*320*sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Comment: My code is almost the same, except that pictureRGB is uint8_t. Does this one have any significance?

Comment: Yes, you have it declared as uint8_t *pictureRGB[4], so you have 32bytes per pixel, when the Bitmap is an RGB565-->16bytes per pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll try the same and thanks for the quick response.